# Layout works but css doesn't work when my view during Index to Details (MVC)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Index : https://i.hizliresim.com/4GJjdJ.png

Details : https://i.hizliresim.com/AylDor.png

I used same layout as :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Fatura";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

But design in details like null.Details page have only layout's words.

Comment: Looks like a problem loading the css files. Check the view source and see the path to the css files are correct ( when you are on details page)

Comment: Well , Try to create new page with reference master layout. hope this will help

Comment: Check your Web project _ViewStart.cshtml file, and define Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" to this file, and delete Layout definition from Details.cshtml file.